# FieldException Error field_update_field() cannot change field's type

Tags: 7, entities

I've got a very strange error and I was hoping someone might be able to help. I'm working on a D7 site (using the latest Acquia version) and it looks like for some reason there is a problem with fields that I cannot isolate.

I'm not sure why this error is being fired - I had a crash because of a problem on the Media Temple side of things earlier, and I had to go back in and manually enable all kinds of modules again.

I've installed D7 Acquia distribution again, and removed anything that might have been corrupted in the files from the crash, but it persists. THis is a core module, so I'm not sure where to begin

FieldException: Cannot change an existing field's type. in field_update_field() (line 234 of /var/www/vhosts/.../modules/field/field.crud.inc).

I can't tell if this was something due to the crash at Media TEmple, or if has something to do with a conflicting module, or what. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful for the help!

Comment: What do you find if you use a debugger on that line?

Comment: Also, did you enable any modules that define a content type? (E.g. anything Features-related, etc.?)

Comment: When you say "this is a core module" which module are you talking about? How were your content types originally defined? (In code? Via the UI?)

Comment: This error occures when a module tries to alter the table schema of another.